# How do I restrict what comes before and after a regex

Tags: regex, lex

I have to create a regular expression to identify emails. Here it's how it looks so far:

`[A-Za-z0-9]+([._-]*[A-Za-z0-9]+)*[@]+[A-Za-z0-9]+([._-]*[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(.com)*`

What I want with this regex is to identify an email. The thing is that the email can't start or finish with any non-alphanumeric symbols. So:

```
.ilikestack@gmail.com or ilikestack@gmail.com_ = invalid
ilike.stack@gmail = valid
```

But when i run the my Lex program the first two emails above are considered valid and I can't figure out how to change this.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the first two are considered valid? That the action associated with your e-mail regex is run for them? What do your other rules and your actions look like; what does your input look like (like is it a list of e-mails separated by something (if so what?) or should the entire file be a single-e-mail or something else; and what do you want to happen for each input (like would you want `.foo@gmail.com` to produce an `INVALID` token followed by an `EMAIL` token (that's what I'd expect to happen already) or something else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to control what can and can't appear before and after a regex is to define another regex, or multiple ones, which match the same thing but surrounded by invalid characters.

So if we had the regex `[a-z]+`, but we only wanted it to match if it was preceded by only white space (or at the beginning of the file) and followed by only white space or a dot (or the end of file), we could accomplish that as follows:

```
[a-z]+                printf("Successful match: '%s'!\n", yytext);
[^a-z \t\r\n][a-z]+   ;
[a-z]+[^a-z \t\r\n.]  ;
.                     ;
```

Then the input `ab cd_ ef. .de fg` would produce the output:

```
Successful match: 'ab'!
Successful match: 'ef'!
Successful match: 'fg'!
```

For your use case, the simplest solution would be to have two additional rules: One for words that start with a non-email non-whitespace character and extend to the next white space character. And one that ends with a non-email character that isn't a dot (or anything else that's allowed to appear after e-mails):

```
[^ \t\r\nA-Za-z0-9][^ \t\r\n]*   ;
[^ \t\r\n]*[^ \t\r\nA-Za-z0-9.]  ;
```

Comment: the format of the code is a little confusing. Basically you made three different regex? One for what comes before, one for what comes in the middle (what you are looking for) and one for what comes after?

Comment: @Giulia I mean, that's the format for lex files: "regex, action, newline, regex, action, newline" and so on. The first line is supposed to match the thing we're looking for (that's why its action prints "Successful match"). The next two lines are supposed to match things that we explicitly don't want to consider matches even though they contain substrings that would otherwise have matches the first rule. The `.` is to match anything else. The actions of those three lines are empty because we don't want to consider these things matches.

Comment: Oh ok, I am new to both regex and lex! It makes sense now!

Comment: Hey, so this really makes sense to me now, but the dot still isnt't woking after an email, and I cant figure out why

Comment: @Giulia Can you post your current lex file, an example input, the output you get and which output you'd want instead?

Comment: I figured it out, I had a line in my rules to capture non-space characters: [[:^space:]]+ turns out that because of the plus sign it had a priority over the rule that allowed the dot. I just erased the + and now it's working! Thanks to you I know a lot more about lex!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty good!

Maybe,

```
(^|\s)[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9._-]*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\s|$)|(^|\s)[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9._-]*@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+(\s|$)|(^|\s)[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9._-]*@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+(\s|$)
```

#### [`Demo 1`](https://regex101.com/r/PYkHSs/1/)

or

```
(^|\s)[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9._-]*@([A-Za-z0-9]+|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)(\s|$)
```

might be somewhat closer.

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/PqJWsf/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/PqJWsf/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

Here we are using a quantifier `{2,6}`, which limits the chars after `@` sign:

#### [`Demo 2`](https://regex101.com/r/WnTsYC/1/)

We can replace that with a `+`, as shown in Demo 2. However, maybe that would not be a good idea.

---

It would be better if you add more boundaries to your expression if you want to validate specific types of emails or domains, such as with,

```
^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9._-]*@[A-Za-z]+\.(?:com|net|org|co)(?:\.uk)?$
```

Otherwise, those above expressions would just pass so many non-email strings as a valid email.

#### [`Demo 3`](https://regex101.com/r/r7NGIO/1/)

Comment: the email doesn't have to be necessarily a real email, so things like LatEX@g can be read as an email. The thing is either the user or the domain of the email cant start or end with non-alphanumerical characters, so:
_stack@gmail isn't valid and stack_@gmail isnt as well or stack@gmail_
I think I wasn't very clear on my question, I am sorry

Comment: Note that this will match one e-mail per line (which I'm not sure whether that's what OP wants or not) and that it won't match the last line if there's no line break at the end of the last line (because `$` requires a line break in lex). Also `(?:)` isn't valid syntax in lex since there's no concept of a capturing group in the first place.

Comment: @sepp2k what I want is to identify all the emails in a phrase. The only non-alphanumeric character after an email is . So if I have a phrase like:
(i) stackoverflow@gmail.com is a very nice email adress, so is (ii) steck_overflow@gmail.com. 
Both (i) and (ii) should be valid emails.

Comment: @Giulia Then this answer won't do what you want (it will only match if the e-mail is the only thing on a line). So when exactly do you not want to match an e-mail? Like what can be in front or after it and what can't? From your examples, apparently a dot can appear after an e-mail, but not in front of it? What else?

Comment: @Emma lex doesn't have a built-in concept of word boundaries (so no `\b`). Usually what can appear around tokens is determined by which other tokens are defined.

Comment: @sepp2k That is exactly it! Only a dot can appear after an email (not before). And the email 'username' cant be finished with non-alphanumerical characters (so stack_@gmail.com is invalid and so is stack.@gmail.com or stack@_gmail.com).
The other relevant thing is that emails can have zero or more domains, so:
stack@gmail or stack@gmail.com or stack@gmail.com.br are all valid

Comment: @sepp2k I've got almost all figured out except for the part that they cant start or finish with non-alphanumerical characters. So what is happening with the regex above: if I have an email stack@gmail.com_ it considers the email (except the _) but if I have an email like stack-@gmail.com it already knows its not valid

Comment: @Emma it works on the emails that have a '.com' but not on others. I am trying to complement your regex with mine to find something, but its not going so far hhahha